# how can I get list of the users data in google play subscriptions

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

Our app has already implemented in-app purchase.

But, we previously don't keep track of it, and only relies on the google's service whether a user's level is premium or regular.

Now, we want to track it in our server as well.

Is it possible to get the users data who've bought our subscriptions? (especially his/her email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from the following documentations, there is no currently existing method to get a list of your app's subscriber's.

- [Google Play Developer - API Reference](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/)
- [In-app Subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

Currently existing features with Google Play Developer API is that, it offers an HTTP-based API that lets you perform such tasks as:

- Remotely query the validity of a specific subscription at any time
- Cancel a subscription
- Defer a subscription's next billing date
- Refund a subscription payment without canceling the subscription
- Refund and revoke a subscription

The API is designed to be used from your backend servers as a way of securely managing subscriptions, as well as extending and integrating subscriptions with other services.

For complete information, you may go through [Google Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html).